# How to pass a variable from a controller, to a view, to the controller again, in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

If I have the `@mis_clases` array variable in the controller:

## bloques_controller

```
def new
  @bloque = Bloque.new
  @mis_clases = Array.new
end
```

And I try to pass it to view, to fill it with clases:

## form.html.erb

```
<div class="card-body">
  <%= form.fields_for :clases do |clase| %>
    <%= render partial: 'clase_fields' %>
    <% @mis_clases << clase %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And access it back in the controller:

## bloques_controller

```
  def create

    @bloque = Bloque.new(bloque_params)

    @mis_clases.each do |clase|
      # Do something
    end

    ...

  end
```

I want to access the variable again when I save the form, but it throws this error:
[image]

Comment: You can share a variable from controller to view by creating an instance variable but you cannot do same other way round. You need to use session to keep the value floating between request because http is stateless protocol.

Answer (score 1):

The naming `instance variable` might be little misleading, but you need to remember that every new request to controller goes to new instance of Controller Class, so even if you create @mis_clases in #new, when reaching #create there is new instance without any variables set, and having nothing in common with recent one but class name.
You should pass variables as field values in form.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that the method did not share the variable. When you say 'pass variables as field values in form', you mean as to be able to access it like `params[my_variable]` in the controller ?